# Crop image from where we want in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to crop the rectangular area I marked on an image with open cv. but this place I marked should not be predetermined.
When the picture is opened, I have to draw a rectangle on the area I want on the picture and crop it.

I can only crop by giving coordinates

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Note that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to show some effort to solve the problem, and ask specific questions about your code.

Comment: Start by Google searching "opencv mouse select rectangle". You may also ask ChatGPT (but don't copy the code from ChatGPT to Stack Overflow question).

Answer (score 0):

you can use OpenCV's event handling capability

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Initialize the list of rectangle points and boolean indicating
# whether cropping is being performed or not
rectangle = []
current_mouse_position = np.ones(2, dtype=np.int32)
cropping = False

def select_rectangle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global rectangle, cropping, current_mouse_position

    # if the left mouse button was clicked, record the starting
    # (x, y) coordinates and indicate that cropping is being
    # performed
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        rectangle = [(x, y)]
        cropping = True

    # keep track of the current mouse position
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        current_mouse_position = np.array([x,y])

    # check to see if the left mouse button was released
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        # record the ending (x, y) coordinates
        rectangle.append((x, y))
        cropping = False # cropping is finished

        cv2.rectangle(image, rectangle[0], rectangle[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)

# load the image, clone it, and setup the mouse callback function
image = cv2.imread("/path/to/image.jpg")
clone = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", select_rectangle)

# keep looping until the 'q' key is pressed
while True:
    if not cropping:
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
    elif cropping and rectangle:
        rect_cpy = image.copy()
        cv2.rectangle(rect_cpy, rectangle[0], (current_mouse_position[0], current_mouse_position[1]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", rect_cpy)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("r"): # press 'r' to reset the selection
        image = clone.copy()
    elif key == ord("c"): # press 'c' to confirm the selection
        break

if len(rectangle) == 2:
    roi = clone[rectangle[0][1]:rectangle[1][1], rectangle[0][0]:rectangle[1][0]]
    cv2.imshow("Cropped", roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```